# getting incorrect result from Hibernate\Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Tomcat: 5.5
Oracle: 11G(11.1.0.7.4)
JDK: 1.6
Hibernate: 3.0.5

**The context**
We are using Hibernate to get rowcount on a view.
The view is written in a way that it will always get at least one row.
In the database, there are enough rows for the view to return 8 rows.

**The problem**
Once in a while, we get count as ZERO

If we try again (i.e the user refreshes screen) correct count of 8 is returned.

**Investigation**
We have tried bunch of things to rule out the following

1) Oracle server returning a bad result
2) Checked the view to make sure it is is good i.e will return correct result

Now the suspicion is turning towards Hibernate

**The code snippet**
Can you spot anything suspicious in the code below ?

```
public static int getRowCount( Criteria criteria )
{
    int totalRows = 0;
    criteria.setProjection( Projections.rowCount() );
    Integer count = ( Integer ) criteria.uniqueResult();

    if ( count != null )
        totalRows = count.intValue();

    criteria.setProjection( null );
    criteria.setResultTransformer( Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY );

    return totalRows;
}
```

We have also verified that the count is zero and not null
Bizarre as it may sound, there are published Oracle defects where it returns incorrect results and moreover this error started happening when we applied an Oracle hot fix.

**Question**
Does anyone think it's possible that Oracle could be returning incorrect result?
Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this would be appreciated as well...

**Summary of some key facts**
- Started happening about the same time when we upgraded Oracle11G from 11.1.0.6.1 to 11.1.0.7.4 and did some hot fixes.
- This was the only change that happened to ecosystem during that time frame- Changes to Oracle
- This happens inconsistently. Now you see the problem- Now you don't.
- Infrequent. But serious enough to cause alarms.

Comment: enable hibernate.show_sql  to verify that hibernate DOES send the correct SQL query

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is turn on Hibernate's query logging. That will tell you exactly what SQL is being sent to Oracle. You can then run that exact SQL and see what you get.

You can turn on query logging with one of the following methods:

- Adjust the org.hibernate.SQL Log Category ([more info](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging))
- Set the Hibernate property `hibernate.show_sql` ([more info](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional))

Comment: You are right. I have a test running right on with logging turned on to zillionth degree- I am using log4jdbc.googlecode.com . In the meantime, I was wondering if there is anything else that I can do to debug (It sometimes takes days to get a hit on our QA env.).Thanks !

Comment: @RN If you have dba access to the database, you could see what sqls are being executed by the application monitoring the current sessions to the database.

Answer (score 1):

v$sql will show the SQL, how many times it has been executed and the number of rows processed.

There's a possibility of an Oracle bug - generally in very complicated queries but also generally consistently for a given data set.

NO_DATA_FOUND exceptions can be raised from PL/SQL procedures and functions, which often appear to a client as an empty result set. Without more details on the view, the tables, and related code....it is all guesswork

Comment: Can I also get the Resultset ?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that Oracle can't get a count right.  Good chance that something else is going on.  Here's a possibility (which I've seen on mat views).  If someone is doing a complete refresh (atomic_refresh=>false for mview), then its like doing a truncate + insert.

If during this refresh you're selecting the count, guess what, the count will = 0.

Just a guess on what could be happening here.  As the DBAs to monitor that view and verify that the refresh isn't occurring while you're selecting a count.

Comment: This is not a Mat view-but a plain old vanilla view.

Answer (score -2):

My two cents:
You have a highly performant Oracle DBMS. Why treat it like a cheap rented mule or a MySql database by fronting it with Hibernate?

It takes just as much effort to learn Oracle PL/SQL and JDBC as it does to learn Hibernate and all its quirks. And the performance difference is just stunning...